# Javascript Validation before storing infomation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sql

I have a group of radio buttons. Two of them are visible at different dates.
I am validating them to ensure atleast one of them is selected before allowing submission.

Here is a table row in my table, Note: In the following scripts I change the input id to the same for all or as a unique id.

```
<tr>
        <td style="width: 120px">Select An Option *:</td>
        <td>
            <div >
                    <h3>text</h3>
                    <?php // date activator

                        $display_start = "2013-09-01";
                        $display_end = "2013-10-17";
                        if((date("Y-m-d") >= $display_start) && (date("Y-m-d") <=
                        $display_end)){ ?>
                        <input id="selection" type="radio" name="group1"  value="Before17th" >  text  here  </option></br></br>

                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php // date activator

                        $display_start = "2013-10-18";
                        $display_end = "2014-10-18";
                        if((date("Y-m-d") >= $display_start) && (date("Y-m-d") <=
                        $display_end)){ ?>
                        <input id="selection" type="radio" name="group1" value="After17th"> text  here   </option><br/></br>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <input id="selection" type="radio" name="group1" value="Already Own Devices">   text  here   </option><br/> 
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

I tried this script for validation, this one only seems to check the first option. If I select the second option it doesn't catch the selection is selected making it true.

```
if ( ($('input[name="group1"]').attr('checked') == false )) {
    $("#errors").after('<span class="error">Please specify an option.</span>');
    hasError = true;
  }
```

I tried this script, with the same input id for all options. This only passes when the first option is selected as well. The second option selected still validates as false.

```
if ( ($("#selection").attr('checked') == false )) {
    $("#errors").after('<span class="error">Please specify an option.</span>');
    hasError = true;
  }
```

I also tried this script, where I gave each input id a unique one. This works well but when I want to POST to my database I would have to create a separate column for each input id.

```
 // validate option selection
if ( ($("#selection").attr('checked') == false ) && ($("#owndevices").attr('checked') == false )) {
    $("#errors").after('<span class="error">Please select an option.</span>');
    hasError = true;
 }

if ( ($("#selection").attr('checked') == false ) && ($("#onsite").attr('checked') == false )) {
    $("#errors").after('<span class="error">Please select an option.</span>');
    hasError = true;
 }
```

Is there a way to make the script validate if one is checked using the same input id. Or maybe using the value or group name?

Thanks

SQL ERROR, I needed to change the html name to group1, and then insert the VALUES. I had put the input id before.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO 
            ucm_signup 
            ( company, address1, address2, city, province, zip, fname, lname, email, phone, 
                session, iama, buyfrom, group1 )
        VALUES
            ( '$_POST[company]','$_POST[address1]','$_POST[address2]','$_POST[city]',
                '$_POST[province]','$_POST[zip]','$_POST[fname]','$_POST[lname]','$_POST[mail]',
                '$_POST[phone]','$_POST[session]','$_POST[iama]','$_POST[buyfrom]','$_POST[]')";
```

Comment: I figured out that I needed to change my SQL statement. My html name to 'group1'. Then it posted the value with VALUES chosen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track with some of what you wrote. But two things to note:

1. Only use one ID per element (group with a name,a class or any other
   attribute you'd like).
2. When you are using jQuery to select more then
   one element then an array is returned.

Try doing something like

```
var radios = $('input[name="group1"]:checked');
if (radios.length > 0) {
        console.log('success'); 
} else {
        console.log('you need at least one radio checked'); 
}
```

Comment: This validated properly. but it looks like I need to have separate input ids. I guess I will make separate columns in my database

Comment: @DDDD Could you select this as the answer. If you need any further explanation let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Well first thing I would do, is I would separate your html code from your php. It's considered bad styling.

In your html file, have your form:

I'm just going to abbreviate the radio buttons, and hopefully you'll get the bigger picture :)

```
<form action="php-to-process.php" method="POST">
 <input type="radio" name="selected" value="male">Something<br>
 <input type="radio" name="selected" value="female">Something<br>
 <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

alright, so what's happening now is when the user hits submit, the selected value goes to the php page. Notice how you're accessing name and not id in the php page.

In your php file you would have something like

```
<?php
  $value = $_POST['selected'];
?>
```

then you can do whatever you're looking to do.

If you don't want a submit button, then you can add an event handler, so something like

```
onClick="document.getElementById("formID").submit();"
```

so when the user clicks that button, the form submits.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Which part is the validation?

Comment: You would do the validation using Javascript. 

user1056677 has the right idea. But try separating your code :)